# WPF component for 2D tree diagram

Tags: wpf, tree, 2d

I'm looking for a well-documented, supported WPF component that provides an API for visualisation of 2D tree diagrams.  Ideally something easy to use, customisable (i.e. supports various flavours of nodes and splines) and preferably with automated layout control.

Tools that look good so far are GoXam (http://www.nwoods.com/components/silverlight-wpf/goxam-overview.htm) and yFiles WPF (http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfileswpf_about.html).

Just wondering if anyone has experience with either of these, or can recommend an alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure:** I work for Mindscape

We build a WPF Diagramming component also that does create tree diagrams as well.

- [WPF Diagrams](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfdiagrams)
- [A recent blog post about the tree layout algorithm](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2011/12/21/wpf-diagrams-new-tree-layout-algorithm/)

It's entirely supported and the team would be happy to help you through the development.

I hope that helps